# why does the job run even if the available network condition isn't verified?

Tags: android, android-service, android-5.0-lollipop, job-scheduling, android-jobscheduler

I'm using jobscheduler since it's no longer possible to declare a network connectivity intent in manifest. I've tried using `.setPeriodic(10 * 1000)` to make the job periodic but in doing so, the job runs after 10 seconds even if there is no available network as if it is ignoring this line `.setRequiredNetworkType(NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)`

And if I remove `.setPeriodic(10 * 1000)` then the job runs only once. What I want to achieve is the same that was possible before the background optimisation and disabling apps from waking based on a connectivity change: If there is an available network then run the jobservice, if there is none do nothing.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main5);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            JobScheduler mJobScheduler = (JobScheduler) getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
            JobInfo.Builder builder = null;
            builder = new JobInfo.Builder(1, new ComponentName(getPackageName(),
                    MyJobService.class.getName()))
                    .setRequiredNetworkType(NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)
                    .setPeriodic(10 * 1000);


        if (mJobScheduler.schedule(builder.build()) <= 0) {
            Log.e("gch", "can't Schedule job for MyJobService");

        } else {
            Log.d("gch", "Schedule job for MyJobService");

        }
        }
}
```

**and this is the jobService**

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public class MyJobService extends android.app.job.JobService {
    public MyJobService() {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
        Log.e("gch", "onStartJob");
        Toast.makeText(this, "onStartJob", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent inent = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);


        inent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        startActivity(inent);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
        Log.e("gch", "onStartonStopJob");
        Toast.makeText(this, "onStartonStopJob", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return true;
    }

}
```

**I've added this to the manifest**

```
 <service
        android:name=".MyJobService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />
```